# problem with multiple percentages in R stacked percentage bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

when i run this code i am only able to get multiple percentages, is there something im missing or have i got an error in my code?

what i expected to happen: create a stacked percentage bar plot with percentage text on the plot to make it easier to visualise the difference in the percentages for ease of use...

any help would be greatly appreciated:)

wanted to happen: have single % text on graph and display it
what actaully happened: showed many percentages and i dont know why this has happened or how to remedy it

```
library(ggplot2)

# Calculate the sum of mpg for each cyl value
sum_mpg <- aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, sum)

# Merge the sum_mpg back into the mtcars dataset
mtcars <- merge(mtcars, sum_mpg, by = "cyl", suffixes = c("", "_sum"))

# Calculate the percentage within each cyl value
mtcars$percentage <- mtcars$mpg / mtcars$mpg_sum

# Create the stacked bar chart with correct percentages displayed
ggplot(mtcars, aes(fill = as.factor(gear), y = percentage, x = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percentage)),
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = "black") +
  labs(title = 'MPG vs Cylinder with Gear Segmentation') +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("Cylinder") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Gear")
```

[image: stacked bar plot with many percentage texts on it]

Comment: Hi @smzimbo Welcome to SE! 
I am not the best ggplot programmer but what I prefer to do is rather than try to calculate these things from the raw dataset, I create a new dataset with the values that I want to present. I think one way would be to create something like "mtcars_new" and then use the ggplot code as you have it. It's just in the way you construct mtcars_new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this all 'inside' ggplot using only the unmodified `mtcars` as input, you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), fill = as.factor(gear), 
                   y = ave(mpg, cyl, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)))) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(y))),
                stat = 'summary', fun = 'sum',
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = "black") +
  labs(title = 'MPG vs Cylinder with Gear Segmentation', x = 'Percentage',
       y = 'Cylinder', fill = 'Gear')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the way you have set up your data you get a label (and a bar) for each car, i.e. your percentage is showing the share of each car on the overall `mpg` of its `cyl` group.

If you want to show the percentage of `gear`s per `cyl` group then aggregate your data by both `cyl` and `gear` and use the aggregated dataset for plotting:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

sum_mpg <- mtcars |>
  group_by(cyl, gear) |>
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) |>
  mutate(percentage = mpg / sum(mpg))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

ggplot(sum_mpg, aes(fill = as.factor(gear), y = percentage, x = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(percentage)),
    position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), size = 4, color = "black"
  ) +
  labs(title = "MPG vs Cylinder with Gear Segmentation") +
  ylab("Percentage") +
  xlab("Cylinder") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Gear")
```

[image]